# How to change default xaml files code layout?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, default

I recently discovered the ability to edit the standard markup for `.cs` files created for Visual Studio. This was done thanks to:

> VS2022 (Enterprise): C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs

But now I'm wondering if there is a similar ability to change the standard code for such `.xaml` files (`UserControl`, `Page`, or `Window`).

It happens very often that there is a need to change the standard parameters for `UserControl`. For example, to set the `DataContext` or to set the `Width` or `Height`. In my case, these parameters are often repeated, so I wanted to find a way to set these parameters in some default file.

Comment: You could find template files for WPF in `... Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\WPF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out [Create a template for a control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-apply-template?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

As emoacht said you can go into ...\Microsoft\VisualStudio\IDE\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\WPF.

[image]

You can modify the parameters in it, and then use it directly next time.

---

You can also use github to store your custom projects and then use [Clone a repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2022) rapid deployment.

[image]